# Visual Studio Tools for Application: How to now the state of the binaries and compile the source from the host application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsta

I integrated Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA) 2019 in my application and basically it works fine.  But I'm unable to find some, in my opinion, key features:

1: I'm unable to determine when my user recompiled the code in the VSTA environment.
I receive the [BinaryItemsChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-tools-for-applications/2015/dn921516(v=vs.140)) event, but this just tells me that the old binaries  are no longer valid. The [ProjectChangeCommitted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-tools-for-applications/2015/mt429791(v=vs.140)) and [ProjectChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-tools-for-applications/2015/dn921521(v=vs.140)) event are only sent when teh source code changes, not when the binaries are recompiled. I cannot find an event which says that new binaries are available. How can an application know when it should load the new assemblies from  the VSTA environment?

2: I also added a macro recording feature, like in excel: when the performs some action, the application generates the appropriate C# and adds this to a method in the VSTA environment. However I was unable to find a way to stat the compilation process in the VSTA environment form the hosting application, so that the user can use the new macro with manually switching the the VSTA editor and compile the newly generated code.  I would like to over the possibility that the user van record a macro and use it without even seeing the VSTA environment. It this possible?

Thanks in advance,
Maurice.